# largest polygon from segments

Tags: computational-geometry

There is a set of segments.
and I want to calculate the area of the largest polygon which can be build using these segments.

I try to search it, but I can't find anything.

thanks

Comment: There is an incomplete answer at http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51828.html which may be worth a look.

Comment: @GerryMyerson aside from the claim the maximal polygon is cyclic, the answer in the link you posted in pretty complete!

Comment: thanks. in these links, we know order of segments but I don't know how to order these segments.

Comment: Voting to reopen. I may be wrong, but I think OP has a point, that in the links, we're given an ordered list of lengths, but in this question, just a set of lengths. Which ordering gives the biggest area? Is it obvious?

Comment: yes, it's obvious.

Comment: Wait a minute --- it's obvious which ordering of the lengths gives the biggest area? Can you tell us which ordering it is?

Comment: no. I mean this is my problem. and you explain it obvious